# String to string array conversion

Tags: java, dbunit

I am using DBUnit and I have faced with problem of string to string array conversion. I am passing dataset file location through `@DatabaseSetup` annotation. Next this location is passed to loader which extends from `AbstractDataSetLoader`(source: http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/cobertura/com.github.springtestdbunit.dataset.AbstractDataSetLoader.html).
In this class exists method

```
public IDataSet loadDataSet(Class testClass, String location) throws Exception {
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = getResourceLoader(testClass);
    String[] resourceLocations = getResourceLocations(testClass, location);
    for (String resourceLocation : resourceLocations) {
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(resourceLocation);
        if (resource.exists()) {
            return createDataSet(resource);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

which invoke getResourceLocations method(this method is implemented in the same class)

```
protected String[] getResourceLocations(Class testClass, String location) {
    return new String[] { location };
}
```

with location parameter(this is my parameter specified in `@DatabaseSetup`). I thought that array declared in such a manner always has to contain only one element, but in `loadDataSet` method I see iteration over an array obtained from `getResourceLocations`. The question is, can getResourceLocations return array which contains more than one element?

Comment: the questions is not completely clear, an array can contain multiple instances, but for this, it needs multiple instances to exist. Unless you can get more strings from testClass or split the `location` string into multiple instances you only have one string to work with. If you want the String-array to output multiple instances, you can use something like `return new String[] { location1, location2 };`

Comment: If your question is just plain "would it be possible", then yes, that is the definition of an array. It can contain multiple instances of the object it represents (a `String` in this case)